# Auto filling field values on New Lead Page

Tags: custom-button, automation, urlhacking, page-override

I have a custom button on one of my custom object, whose purpose is to create a New Lead Record, by showing the fields to the users, they fill up the form and lead gets saved. The saved Lead Id will be populated in the Lookup field on the object on which the button exists.

If I have a visualforce page of my own showing up necessary Lead fields, any future addition of fields in the Lead will require me to update my code every time.

Is there a way that on clicking the button I get redirected to the standard New Page for Creating a lead, with certain values auto-filled. For Example,

FirstName would be by default populated with the current record's First Name value on which the button was existing.

I have tried the following code already in the button URL :

```
/00Q/e?retURL=%2F00Q%2Fo&FirstName='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Contact_First_Name__c}'&LastName='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Contact_Last_Name__c}'&Email='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Email__c}'
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are passing the parameters in `returnURL` instead of after `e?`. The parameters should be passed before return URL `/00Q/e?FirstName='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Contact_First_Name__c}'&LastName='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Contact_Last_Name__c}'&Email='{!Partner_Deal__c.End_User_Email__c}&retURL=%2F00Q%2Fo'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do it in 3 steps, and it works:

1/ find the ID of the field you want to auto-fill:

Personally, i get the URL by inspecting the html code of the field :

[image]

you can refer to this page for standard object field Ids http://theblogreaders.com/salesforce-standard-object-field-ids/#.V1a0Vtl97Dc

2. **Create the button**

Select **URL** as a content source and add the following URL with your org instance of course. I created the button on the opportunity object (you can change the object) in order to populate the lead name with the opportunity name. it's just an example, you can add as many fields as you want:

[image]

3. **add the button to the page layout of your object**.